# DAX - Running Percentage Over Time?

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax, trend

I'm working on plotting a Percentage Over Time.  I have my measures configured and working properly on a daily basis but what I would like is for a running percentage / rolling average.

I've attached the Table, Rate Formula, Percentage Formula and Graph. The Graph lets me know that it is doing the calculation on a daily basis instead of a rolling basis by the huge difference of today's date.

```
    Rolled Rate = 
VAR STARTDATE = FIRSTDATE('Date'[Date])
VAR Result = 
CALCULATE( 
'RAW - ALL'[RR Division],
'RAW - ALL'[LCRBA Approved TimeStamp] >= STARTDATE,
ALL('RAW - ALL')
)
RETURN 
    Result

    RTN = 
VAR STARTDATE = FIRSTDATE('Date'[Date])
VAR RESULT = 
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('RAW - ALL'[TicketNumber]), 
FILTER('RAW - ALL', 'RAW - ALL'[Final Status] = "LCRB Approved"), 
FILTER('RAW - ALL', NOT 'RAW - ALL'[Discussion Thread Topic] = "N/A"),
FILTER ('RAW - ALL', 'RAW - ALL'[LCRBA Approved TimeStamp] >= STARTDATE))
RETURN
Result



  RR Division = 
 calculate (DIVIDE([RTN],'RAW - ALL'[ATD],0))
```

I can't post pictures, reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: Pictures don't help anyone. Post you sample data as markdown table.

Comment: The data includes sensitive information, so I can't post publicly. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Abstract the problem and provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want others to help you.

Comment: I thought that’s what I did. With  examples of the measures. But will try again.

Comment: So far 28 people have been interested in your problem. Since there is no answer yet, probably none of them could reproduce your question. What does that tell about your abstraction skills?